# Windows cannot see SSD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, ssd

I just added an ssd to my father's computer. The computer recognizes it being there (I can see it in the boot screen). In the bios I can choose to boot to it. I wanted to install windows 8 to it. On the setup screen, it didn't appear as a choice. In windows 7 I opened Disk Management and it doesn't appear there either. I live booted ubuntu and was able to format the drive there as NTFS. Still no luck.

The hard drive is [Crucial M500](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/storage-ssd-m500) and the computer is [HP e9240f](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-Pavilion-Elite-e9000-Desktop-PC-series/3999455/model/4007353/document/c01896260/)

HHD is MBR

[image: BIOS shot 1]
[image: BIOS shot 2]

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you use UEFI or BIOS mode? Is the HDD GPT or MBR style?

Comment: I'm not sure (either), how do I check. I've included shots of the bios if it helps.

Comment: Try to change sata controller mode to one of the other options, whichever they are

Comment: @magicandre1981 HHD is MBR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows cannot see the drive because your SATA controller mode (screenshot #2 above) is set to RAID.  Unless you plan on doing a multi-drive RAID setup, it needs to be set to AHCI.